# Jenkins Post Action Build to change status

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, automated-tests

Is there a way to read a file post build in Jenkins and change the status of the build?

Currently, I am running my Python Selenium using Jenkins by calling a batch command file to run the python file. My Selenium Python class will automatically generate a .log file at the end of the run. And Jenkin will attach the log file and send email to me.

But, the problem is Jenkins always says it as a success regardless of the status of the results in the log file.

Is there any way to read a few lines from the log file in Jenkins post build and change the status of the build accordingly before sending the email?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to generate your test results as JUnit file, jenkins can pick that up and your build status is automatically changed. What Test Execution framework you use. Defining own Data Formats or log file is not a good idea.

Try to use standard formats and you get a plugin for it. Define your own formats and then you have to implement everything around it